# Center marker in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to center a Google map in an iframe. The code below is the content of the iframe.
The marker is not in the center of the frame.

What is missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $this->uri->segment(5); ?>', '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>');
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title:"Hello World!"
          });

         }


        initialize();


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I think I have solved it buy setting a fixed size for the map_canvas instead of using 100%.
I works much better now.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is when I put it inside of an iframe it is no longer centered.

Comment: @Engineer. Please create an answer and I will choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/yRHJv and in `jsfiddle` the map is inside of `iframe`.

I have replaced your PHP code with some dummy data.